# How to display the null values of 2D array as 0 in C++?

Tags: c++

i am trying to display a matrix using 2D array (int matrix[ ][ ]) .
now after i created the array i am trying to display it back, but there is always null values in the array, and it shows this number (-858993460) in the place of the null value.
i did a lot of research and i found out that the array should display 0 in the places of null values which what i want, but that doesn't happen in my case.

this how i display the array values:
...

```
for (int i = 0; i < row_num; i++)
{
    cout << " }";
    cout << endl << "{  ";
    for (int j = 0; j < column_num; j++)
    {
        cout << matrix[i][j];
        cout << "  ";
    }

}
}
```

...

and here is how i stored the elements of the array

```
struct Node *temp, *r, *s;
temp = r = s = start;
int matrix[10][10];
while (temp != NULL || r != NULL || s != NULL)
{
    matrix[temp->row][r->column] = s->value;
    temp = temp->next;
    r = r->next;
    s = s->next;
}
```

...

i added 1 and 2 and 2 to specific positions in the array as input when the program ran, and i left the rest of the array empty.
here is the output:

```
{  1  -858993460  -858993460   }
{  2  -858993460  -858993460   }
{  -858993460  2  -858993460   }
```

Comment: `temp = r = s = start` - then why have 3 different variables for the same thing?

Comment: it is to start the linked list data retrieving process, so i set all the values as start.

Comment: `matrix` contains values of type `int`. It cannot contain NULL.

Comment: Always initialize your variable: `int matrix[10][10] = {0};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please initialize your 2d array to 0 first.

```
int arr[10][10] = {0}
```

To avoid any garbage values being entered by the compiler.

Comment: The compiler doesn't create garbage values if you don't initialize it. Or *any* values.  Rather, whatever data *already exist* at that point in memory will be interpreted as `int`s.

Comment: That is my meaning of garbage values. The compiler has to output something. That something is garbage, because the values have nothing to do with what we need.

Comment: Theoretically, a platform that has status bits for a byte of memory which make that byte write-only (until initialized) and trap (halting the program) if it is read from would be a dangerous kind of garbage value to use uninitialized.

Comment: @Ray: That is naive and generally false. When the compiler sees that the value has never been initialized or assigned, it might not even bother to access that memory, and instead do something else, like "create" garbage values.

Comment: @AnT Accessing an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior, so it would be free to do that. (Simply *having* uninitialized variables is perfectly legal).  And since it's undefined, the compiler is free to write garbage values to those locations if it wants to. It could also write garbage values to any other location, or explode, or print a recipe for German chocolate cake.  Once we're bringing undefined behavior into the mix, assuming that it will do one *specific* thing like creating garbage values isn't the right approach either. But you are correct that we can't *rely* on anything here.

Answer (score 0):

So there is nothing that requires that an array have all 0's in it or NULL values when you first initialize it. It would have whatever was in memory prior to that section of memory being allocated for an array. You should at the beginning of your program, iterate through the matrix and set all values to 0 and then proceed. You can also probably get away with a call to memset

Comment: this is not the right way of doing it as it consumes more of the memory

Comment: Always initialize your variable: int matrix[10][10] = {0};  by Amadeus      
this is the right way of doing it 
thanks again Amadeus

Comment: @ahmedselim It doesn't consume more memory; the memory is allocated as soon as you say `int matrix[20][20]` (or whatever the dimensions).  Using memset may be `slower` than a static initialization, depending on the scope of the matrix; it may be possible for it to be initialized during compilation.